# Conda - VS Code: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, geopandas

I'm kind a new Python user - using Anaconda Python and VS code. I'm trying to launch my jupyter notebook, but I'm not able to import geopandas.

```
import geopandas
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import geopandas

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'
```

I can see geopandas in 'conda list' in myenv, but still if I want to check it in my jupyter notebook I get negative response

```
import sys
'geopandas' in sys.modules

False
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9veY.png)

I already tried a lots of advices from here and git hub, but I'm not able to figure it out.

Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Run `!conda list geopandas` from your jupyter notebook and check that your notebook is running in the `myenv` conda environment

Comment: It look like jupyter notebook calls it from root dir C:\Users\xy\Anaconda3, but same thing it does for pandas or numpy, which are work fine.

Comment: Pandas and Numpy are installed in the conda base environment by default. You need to launch your jupyter notebook from the correct conda environment (`myenv`), or configure VS code to use that conda environment if you choose to run your jupyter notebook within VS code

Comment: Did you follow the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for using environments in VSCode?

Comment: Thnx all for help! I have to reinstall VS code, remove my conda environment, create a new one and after all I was finally able to open functional jupyter notebook and run geopandas.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with visual studio code. For me there is a button in the upper right corner of the VS Code window with the current environment selected. I clicked it and it allows me to change the kernel for the notebook :
[image: check this screenshot]

This is assuming you have the dependencies installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the `geopandas library` before? If you don't do this before Please open your anaconda prompt form start menu and command the below lines

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

and then press the enter button.

After that, You may apply below the line on your code

Update Code:

```
from geopy import geocoders # For matching the buildings' cities with time zones
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut # Catch timeouts while using Google geocoding API
from geopy.exc import GeocoderUnavailable # Catch other network problems
```

Comment: Yes, I did.

`(cash_h) C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\cash_h>conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
# All requested packages already installed.
`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are sure that you can access the environment on jupyter,

What you have to do is to to manually install the packages.

Go to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/), to download the compatible version for GDAL, Pyproj, Fiona, Shapely and Geopandas.

Then manually installed each using:

pip install the_file_path_to_the_downloaded_file

I hope this helps!